# Permission Denied as root when connecting BluetoothSocket with Bluez 5.43

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspbian-stretch, permissions

I've been trying to get bluetooth working on my Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+ running Raspbian Stretch Lite 4.14 with a 3rd party USB bluetooth dongle.

I installed Bluez 5.43 for python 2.7, and was able to pair with another device using `bluetoothctl`. However, when I then try to connect a `BluetoothSocket` to that device, I get `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (13, 'Permission denied')`.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599703/rfcomm-bluetooth-permission-denied-error-raspberry-pi) with the same issue, and it was resolved by running `sudo python script.py`.

However, when I do the same and run the python script with `sudo`, the program still fails with the same error.

[This is my python script.](https://github.com/coolioasjulio/EV3-Auto-Turret/blob/Bluetooth/bluetoothtest.py) It is Python2.7 running on Raspbian Stretch Lite 4.14 using Bluez 5.43.

Comment: did you also try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306883/5053002) in that same thread?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I tried that solution as well, which also failed. After doing those steps, I still receive the same error.